# TypeError that only occurs after several executions when starting processes

Tags: python, debugging, process

I seem to have a very weird error. The following code works two or three times, then ends with a TypeError

```
cmd = "perl prog.pl"
process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE)
matchstr=process.communicate()
exit_code = process.wait()
print exit_code 

embedded_rawstr = r"""Extract"(?P<ex>.*?)".*?"""
print re.findall(embedded_rawstr, matchstr)
```

The code is called within a loop, so its called fairly often. Why does this Error occur and how can I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ga-test.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "ga-test.py", line 65, in main
    fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))
  File "ga-test.py", line 47, in evalOneMax
    print re.findall(embedded_rawstr, matchstr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you post the message?

Comment: added error traceback

Comment: i suspect that the matchstr that comes from the process is empty. how can this happen?

Comment: but when i leave out the line findall, i get exit codes 0 all across the board. And i get sensible values for matchstr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Popen.communicate()` returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).

Replace following:

```
matchstr = process.communicate()
```

with:

```
matchstr, stderr = process.communicate()
```